# Необходимо выбрать из словаря наибольшие значения и записать их интервал

Tags: python, словари

У меня есть словарь, содержащий ключ(время) и значение(количество). Мне необходимо выбрать из этого словаря элементы с наибольшими значениями, и записать интервал времени между ними. Как это можно осуществить? Словарь выглядит следующим образом, так же значения могут идти беспорядочно, а не по возрастанию:

```py
time = {
    '08:30': 1,
    '09:00': 2,
    '09:30': 3,
}
```

и так далее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
time = {'08:30': 1, '09:00': 2, '09:30': 3,}
sorting = sorted(list(time.items()), key=lambda times: times[1])
top_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(sorting[-1][0], '%H:%M')
second_top_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(sorting[-2][0], '%H:%M')
delta_time = top_time - second_top_time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time = {
    '10:05': 4,
    '08:30': 1,
    '09:00': 2,
    '09:30': 3,
}

myList = sorted([ [time[i],i] for i in time  ], reverse=True)

h = int(myList[0][1][:2]) - int(myList[1][1][:2])
m = int(myList[0][1][3:]) - int(myList[1][1][3:])
h, m = (h, m) if m>=0 else (h-1, m+60)

print( "{:>02}:{:>02}".format(h, m) )
00:35
```